# How to get particular row of data in Strongly typed view in MVC application..?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5.2

My view index.cshtml (strongly typed view with class name:BusDetails.cs)contains code like below:

```
model IEnumerable<MVC_DAL.BusDetails>

@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "AddBus")

<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BusSrlNo)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BusName)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) 
 {
 <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelIte => item.BusSrlNo)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BusName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.BusSrlNo }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.BusSrlNo */ })| 
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.BusSrlNo */ })|

    </td>
  </tr>
 }

</table>
```

This works fine to get results as in image below.
But if I want's to get particular row of data in output,let's say 4th rows data BusName=Kukke to some other purpose, How can I get it.?

Also my BusDetails.cs contains code as below.

```
 public class BusDetails
  {
    public int BusSrlNo { get; set; }
    public string BusName { get; set; }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by _get the row_? What do you want to do with that data?

Comment: Where do you want to access this data on the View? Controller?

Comment: @CodeRatchet--On view i want to access..

Comment: @Jasen--That means i want get data which is at particular row,say like BusName 'Kukke' and id is 4 at 4th row in the view, then how i can do it..?Because i want dispaly it seperately..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `ElementAt(index)` like so:

```
BusDetails item4 = Model.ElementAt(3);
```

and you can use the data in the view like this:

```
<div>4th bus name: @item4.BusName</div>
<div>4th bus number: @item4.BusSrlNo</div>
```

Comment: I directly wrote like  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ElementAt(3).BusName). Then it's worked me..Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
var kukkeBuses = Model.where(x => x.BusName == "Kukke")

@foreach (var item in kukkeBuses){
  ........
}
```

Or try this - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery, you can do this to find a particular row in table -

```
    $("#MyTable").find("tbody tr").each(function(){
    var busName = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text(); //1 is the index of column BusName
       if (busName =='Kukke'){
       //Do whatever you would like to do here, with your row, which is $(this)
       }
    });
```